# can not detect json from page source after opening from selenium

Tags: python, json, selenium

i'm using selenium to get the "dynamic content" after searching the letter *'a'* then save the table to a json file .

i tried using `json.loads(html)` directly it didn't work , then i tried `encode('utf-8').decode('ascii','ignore')` on the html but also didn't work

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import json
driver=webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="chromedriver")
driver.get("http://example.webscraping.com/places/default/index")
driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/ul/li[2]/a').click()
elem=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="search_term"]')
elem.send_keys("a")
elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
html=driver.page_source.encode('utf-8').decode('ascii','ignore')
driver.close()
print json.loads(html)
```

this is what i want as output so then i can save it to text file.

```
{"records": [{"pretty_link": "<div><a href=\"/places/default/view/Afghanistan-1\"><img src=\"/places/static/images/flags/af.png\" /> Afghanistan</a></div>", "country": "Afghanistan", "id": 3506077}, {"pretty_link": "<div><a href=\"/places/default/view/Aland-Islands-2\"...
```

this is the error i am receiving `raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded`

Comment: What output are you getting now?

Comment: @DebanjanB i am getting an error message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSON cannot *be detected* because requested page (and `driver.page_source`) returns you *HTML*, while you need to request *JSON*. Try this code to get required output

```
import requests

print requests.get('http://example.webscraping.com/places/ajax/search.json?&search_term=a&page_size=10&page=0').json()
```

If you need `records` only:

```
response = requests.get('http://example.webscraping.com/places/ajax/search.json?&search_term=a&page_size=10&page=0').json()
print response['records']
```

To get country names:

```
for item in response['records']:
    print item['country']
```

Output:

```
'Afghanistan'
'Aland Islands'
'Albania'
'Algeria'
'American Samoa'
'Andorra'
'Angola'
'Anguilla'
'Antarctica'
'Antigua and Barbuda'
```